# Is it useful to setup SPF for shared hosting domain

Tags: spf

I am little confused right now:

As far as I understand SPF-records are supposed to validate the MAIL-FROM and probably HELO from a sending mailserver. 
If I am in a shared hosting environment, where I do not have access to the mail servers configuration, why should I add a SPF record to my domains DNS?

For example in the 1and1 doku I found: https://help.1and1.com/domains-c36931/manage-domains-c79822/dns-c37586/explanation-of-an-spf-record-a792807.html which suggests, I should add

```
 include:_spf.kundenserver.de
```

to the SPF record.

But when I look at the MAIL FROM and EHLO information, when I send an email from test@exampledomain.com it only contains:

```
$receivingServer>> grep 'MAIL FROM' /var/log/mail.log
mout.kundenserver.de[212.227.126.133]: MAIL FROM:<cgi-mailer-bounces-373775065@kundenserver.de> SIZE=1534

$receivingServer>> grep 'EHLO' /var/log/mail.log
mout.kundenserver.de[212.227.126.133]: EHLO mout.kundenserver.de

$receivingServer>> grep 'exampledomain.com' /var/log/mail.log
[empty]
```

So my question is: Is it really useful to add the suggested SPF-Record include in this environment? Does the SPF-Validator ever look at the FROM-Domain in the Email-Headers?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EHLO/HELO does not matter, it is only recommended by the standard and often ignored. With SPF, the receiver checks if the sending server (which is not necessarily exactly the same as it's hostname/address) is allowed to send emails for the domain of the MAIL FROM-address.

So if someone receives a mail from `user@exampledomain.com` (as the envelope's FROM / Return-Path), it can be checked if the sending server is allowed to do that. If the sending servers are only those provided by your provider, use `include:_spf.kundenserver.de -all`.

If you do not send emails with your domain as MAIL-FROM, you can set it to `-all`.

Comment: This seems to contradict what is documented here http://www.openspf.org/RFC_4408#helo-ident about HELO and MAIL FROM and Checking Authorization - or am I missing something?

Comment: A recommendation is not a requirement. It would be great (really!) if helos would be not malformed, but sadly this is often not the case. This is also stated in the first paragraph you linked.

Comment: Are you referencing the from-header or the MAIL-FROM envelope email? Because in a shared hosting environment I am most likely not able to configure "MAIL FROM" envelope email

Comment: It's the envelope's MAIL FROM / Return-path. See also: http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/Envelope_from_scope

Comment: @SomeoneYouDontKnow Please upvote and/or accept my answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

In this specific example, some things got mixed up: your message has been sent from a shared hosting webspace, which automatically adds a generic MAIL FROM-address (cgi-mailer-bounces-${some_id}@kundenserver.de) whenever your mail-sending script didn't specify one (using "sendmail -f sender@domain.tld").
So in this example, your own domain isn't used at all. The used domain (kundenserver.de) does have an SPF record including the used mail server 212.227.126.133, so the pure SPF check does work fine for the example message - but this is probably not the kind of configuration you'd like to use, as you might run into further trouble.

In general, SPF records are important for any kind of mail-sending domain, regardless where or how it's being hosted.

SPF on it's own can protect your domain from being flooded with bounces of illegitimate spam messages (using your domain name in MAIL FROM).

Adding an SPF record to your domain specifies which mail servers are permitted to deliver mail on behalf of your domain. This can protect (to some extent) your domain from being abused by spammers but also (slightly) vouches in your favor when sending mail.

Simplified:

- if there's an SPF record present and the sending server is on that SPF record's list, the message is regarded as a "genuine" mail from your domain. This doesn't guarantee your mail to be delivered as "non-spam"; however, if your sending server is not on the SPF record's list, the message is more likely to be rejected or sent into the recipient's "spam" folder.
- if there's no SPF record (and nothing like DKIM) present for your mail/domain, the receiving server doesn't know if the message has been legitimately sent from your domain. As most legitimate mails are being sent using SPF and/or DKIM, a spam filter on the receiving mail server might more likely route your message as "potential spam" into the recipient's "spam" folder.
- if the MAIL FROM-address is empty, there's no address or domain where error messages/bounces are to be sent to; usually, this is only used for sending bounces. In this special case, the SPF record for the domain used in HELO/EHLO is being used.

Aside of SPF, it's also necessary to mention DKIM and DMARC.

SPF is the oldest, but also knowingly weakest standard. SPF doesn't validate the message's From-header, so doesn't protect from certain phishing cases. SPF is known to give unexpected results whenever messages are automatically being forwarded (the forwarding server is unlikely to be listed in your domain's SPF records, so forwarding may fail).

In SPF, there's some confusion about how the default policy is to be used. SPF checks can be performed at SMTP level before the actual message is being read for delivery, so a "hard" SPF policy (-all) may have severe side-effects and may apply before any other checks or spam filters do. So in general, a neutral (?all) or soft-failing (~all) default policy are recommended for SPF. SPF then effectively becomes a voucher in favor of your legitimately sending mail servers.

DKIM does address some issues with SPF, but is less easy to implement than SPF. DKIM requires adding cryptographic private keys to your mail server and a special TXT record for your domain (the corresponding public key). Whenever your mail server does (legitimately) send mail using your domain and does support DKIM, it does add a digital signature on a range of other message headers (including the From-Header) to prove the message has been legitimately being sent using your domain. The receiving server then can validate that signature (a special header) using the DKIM-specific TXT-record.
DKIM doesn't have a default policy: a valid signature is just a voucher in favor of that message, invalid signatures are to be ignored (they might become accidentally broken while being forwarded via some mailing list service).

It's important for your domain/mail server to support SPF, DKIM or at best both standards.

DMARC does combine SPF and DKIM along with its own policy:

- The domain used in MAIL FROM must either be exactly the same or a subdomain of the domain used in the message's From-header - or empty (for bounce messages). The default-added "cgi-mailer-bounces-${some_id}@kundenserver.de" will most likely break DMARC), so you should specify your domain when sending mail.
- if any DKIM-signature-header does validate with the domain used in the message's From-header, DMARC does accept the message.
- if an SPF record is present and the SPF-check validates for the domain used in the message's "From"-Header (not the MAIL FROM-domain), DMARC does accept the message.
- DMARC does clearly specify how DMARC violations are to be handled: ignore ("monitor mode"), reject or route to spam folder. DMARC also specifies if and how such violations are to be reported.

Support for DMARC is growing among the industry.

And that's the entire answer to your question:
- when you're using DMARC, receiving mail servers do evaluate your SPF record with the message's From-header.
- you should at least add an SPF record to your domain, using both your webhost-recommended "include:_spf.kundenserver.de" and either a neutral ("?all") or soft-fail ("~all")default policy.
- If your host does support DKIM, use it as well (otherwise: ask them to support it…).
- Both SPF and DKIM do enhance (or: their absence may decrease) your chance of getting your messages delivered successfully. You should support at least one of them.
- you might want to look into using DMARC, as it does make use of SPF and DKIM while fixing a few issues with both standards. Using DMARC without DKIM (so only relying on SPF) is not recommended unless you really do know what exactly you're doing.